# How is data in a site change without ajax request or url changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was looking at the https://www.dotnetperls.com/ and when i click on 'C#' link in the page the page loads with different content and i dont see any ajax request in the Network tab in the browser and there no url change also.

How is this achieved?

Comment: probably a javascript event hooked up with jquery to present a list. Press F12 in your browser and put a breakpoint in the javascript functions and you'll find what function is being called.

Comment: you can debug it yourself in your browser and see what happens. But almost certainly it just uses JavaScript to reveal and navigate to some content which was previously loaded but hidden using CSS styles. Pretty normal, basic stuff really. It's also possible that the HTML content is actually created on-the-fly by the JavaScript code, and then inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the content is already loaded into the page when you first visit the site. If you look at Event Listeners in Chrome for the link, you'll see javascript hooked in to change the rendered HTML element on click.

Answer (score 4):

The whole content is loaded in the first request and when you click on "C#", the default content and the rest is displayed using JavaSript without loading anything new.

If you click on "examine this element" in your browser for the "C#" link, you'll see that the content is still in the page after the "new" content was displayed, it was just hidden.